# Useless escaping in chat codes

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, code-formatting

When someone posts a rather long code fragment in chat it is shortened and a link to a separate page is created. The linked page is send as `text/plain`. But the code is escaped as HTML.

This makes the code hard to read. It is not necessary.

[Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/6/4295268)

Comment: +1 And Gists are pasted as full link, which may take another whole screen height.

Comment: What do you mean "a link to a separate page is created"? A "show more" link is created, which you click to expand the shortened post. You're never supposed to directly see the page you've linked to.

Comment: I open long code blocks in a separate tab. Didn't even _know_ it opens inline too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intended scenario there is that the sample is opened inline via the expansion link provided, hence why it is formatted . I'm not sure it ever occurred to me that people would try opening it as a separate page. However, what you say is not an *unreasonable* usage. I'll see what we can do.

Comment: I personally tend to ctrl-click any link that comes my way--remember, I don't know what the link does till I click it. If I don't want to lose my place in a particularly long page(chat transcripts etc), then I'll first ctrl-click on a link. If it turns out to be a JS link, _then_ I'll normal click it. But that's just me :P